# How to make GHC generate dynamically linked binaries by default?

Tags: haskell, cabal

*Is it possible to change cabal or GHC settings so that `cabal install` generates dynamic binaries and libraries by default?*

I'm using GHC 8.2.2, installed using `apt-get` in Ubuntu (16.04) without Haskell Platform or stack. Searching around, I found the SO question [Why can't cabal build mighttpd2 dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12232471/683218) . The answers/comments there said something about adding `--enable-shared --enable-executable-dynamic` when `cabal install`. And this can be done **manually** for all dependency libraries (which would be a pain).

In [Small Haskell program compiled with GHC into huge binary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6115459/683218), the accepted answer says that one needs to:

```
cabal install some_package --enable-shared --reinstall
```

The option `-dynamic` is also mentioned.

My question is:

Is it possible to change the options in the cabal configuration file (`~/.cabal/config`) from the very beginning so that all binaries and their dependency libraries use dynamic linkage (i.e. with `--enable-shared` `--enable-executable-dynamic` or `-dynamic` by default)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, you can alter your `~/.cabal/config` file to have the following lines:

```
shared: True
executable-dynamic: True
```